# Can I use Page.IsPostBack from BasePage?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a web form page Default.aspx, which inherits from a BasePage class that I created, which in turn inherits from System.Web.UI.Page.  Very common setup.

```
Default : BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
```

Within the `BasePage.BasePage()` (constructor), I want to do something if we're not doing a postback.  So I put the standard

```
 if(!Page.IsPostBack)
 {
    // do stuff here
 }
```

However, `Page.IsPostBack` always returns false, even when I am really posting back.

My question, then, is this just a limitation of BasePage not being able to see the `IsPostBack` variable on the page level?

Or is there an extra piece I'm missing like when I must say `HttpContext.Current.Request` instead of just `Request` on the page level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't put it in the constructor.  The IsPostBack value is valid within the lifecycle events PreInit through Load.

Comment: I see.  Looking into your answer further I found a chart of the life cycle at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx that was helpful and seems to support what you're saying as far as when IsPostBack becomes available.  I need to set some variables up for use in the the Page_PreInit section, so I either need to put all that code in there, or just figure on not haveing IsPostBack available.  Thanks for your help.